# Junk characters in htttps get response

Tags: c++, windows, https, fiddler

I am facing a weird situation with a Windows application (OCX control) written in C++, which was working fine until 2 days ago. No updates were added to the application. Then suddenly, it started to have errors in the communication with a remote test server. Basically, the error is that in the response of a `GET` request, I am seeing junk characters like this: `ÑòWo  †¶âBA etc`

The function that I am using for the HTTP requests is:

```
TCHAR* openUrlFunction(TCHAR *strServer, TCHAR *strPath, TCHAR *userAgent){

    HINTERNET   httpSession = NULL;
    HINTERNET   httpConnect = NULL;
    HINTERNET   httpRequest = NULL;
    HINTERNET   hFile = NULL;
    BOOL        resDownload = FALSE;
    TCHAR       bufferIdent[60] = { 0 };
    TCHAR       bufferMirror[500] = { 0 };
    TCHAR       szURL[200] = { 0 };
    TCHAR       sError[7] = { 0 };
    DWORD       dwFlags;
    //  DWORD       dwTimeOut = 25000;
    DWORD       dwBuffLen = sizeof(dwFlags);
    int         i = 0;
    DWORD       dwRead, error;
    int         len;
    TCHAR       *res1;
    TCHAR       delimeter[6] = _T("\f\n\r\t\v");

    HRESULT resCat;

    
    bufferIdent[0] = '\0';
    bufferMirror[0] = '\0';
    szURL[0] = '\0';

    std::string ss;

    httpSession = InternetOpen(strAgent, INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_PRECONFIG, NULL, NULL, 0); // header 

    if (httpSession)
    {
        httpConnect = InternetConnect(httpSession, strServer, INTERNET_DEFAULT_HTTPS_PORT, NULL, NULL, INTERNET_SERVICE_HTTP, 0, 0); 

        if (httpConnect)
        {
            httpRequest = HttpOpenRequest(httpConnect, "GET", strPath, NULL, NULL, NULL, INTERNET_FLAG_SECURE, 0);  parametros.

            if (HttpSendRequest(httpRequest, NULL, 0, NULL, 0)) {  
                if (httpRequest)
                {
                    while (InternetReadFile(httpRequest, bufferMirror, 499, &dwRead)) // Se lee el retorno
                    {
                        if (dwRead == 0)
                            break;

                        StrTrim(bufferMirror, delimeter);

                        while (bufferMirror[i] != NULL){  

                            if (bufferMirror[i] != char(10))
                                ss = ss + bufferMirror[i];
                            i++;
                            if (bufferMirror[i] == char(10))  
                                break;
                        }
                        i = 0;
                    }
                }
            }
            else{

                error = GetLastError();
                _stprintf_s(sError, 7, _T("%d"), error);
                InternetCloseHandle(httpRequest);
                InternetCloseHandle(httpConnect);
                InternetCloseHandle(httpSession);
                return sError;
            }
            InternetCloseHandle(httpRequest);  
        }
        InternetCloseHandle(httpConnect);
    }
    InternetCloseHandle(httpSession);

 

    len = ss.length();

    if (len == 0){
        return NULL;
    }
    res1 = new TCHAR[len + 1];

    resCat = StringCchCopyN(res1, len + 1, ss.c_str(), len);

    if (!SUCCEEDED(resCat))
        return NULL;

    return res1;
}
```

The interesting thing here was that I decided to monitor the traffic so I have installed Fiddler on the same machine (Windows 10) where the problem is happening. After started Fiddler, I made a test with the Application and voila, the response was clear and well-formed and no junk characters were present.

I suspect that the Fiddler Everywhere Certificate that is installed has something to do with the result. So, if I turn off Fiddler, and make a new test, I again receive the junk characters.

I have checked the TLS configuration in the computer and nothing is wrong there. I am not sure if a Windows update could have caused this situation.

We have 3 machines, and the problem is occurring on 2 of the 3. All of them are Windows 10, but maybe different updates.

One other important thing here is that the server is for testing, and the client did not install any SSL certificate.

Comment: You are only checking whether `dwRead` is zero, then assume everything else in the buffer that isn’t `\0` is data, but if e.g. `dwRead == 1` only the first byte in the buffer is actual data that’s been read, the other `499 - dwRead` bytes are junk. You need to properly use `dwRead` to determine how many bytes were read into the buffer on each call to `InternetReadFile`.

Answer (score 0):

Well after looking into this problem, I just found that the root of the issue was more related to the fact the one of the variables was not correctly initialized and before the http request, this variable could contain junk characters so the next steps of the process were affected for the garbage that the variable contained. Another thing was that the connection problem with WININET was solved after installing a right SSL certificate. Even after setting some flags to bypass the SSL validation, did not work. The connection only was possible when the server was configured with the SSL certificate.